# Does Apache Ftp Server (java) SFTP work for anyone?

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

After trying to get sftp working ive ended up with the simplest possible sample that does not work. Basically I have created a simple class with main and copied the 2nd (SFTP) example from http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/embedding-ftpserver-in-5-minutes.html. The server starts without any exceptions but no client (winscp, cuteftp etc) all fail to connect. Im completely baffled any pointers would be appreciated...im guessing im missing something completely obvious.

Comment: Are you setting the port to connect to on the client side? The example appears to use the non-default port of 2221

Comment: +1 @Andrew. Also, if you're not using a local client, could a firewall interfere with your connection? Can you post a log from your client(s)?

Comment: You can't expect an FTP server to act as an SSH server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you cant create an SFTP server only ftp over ssl :(

Answer (score 6):

SFTP and FTPS are completely different protocols.

SFTP is related to SSH. Java implementations include:

- Maverick - a commercial implementation
- Apache Mina SSHD - part of the open source Apache Mina project

FTPS is FTP over SSL. There are many, many implementations, including Apache FTPServer.